# Django query to extract values when there is an intermediate table

Tags: django, django-models

My database has the following structure.

```
Table1: 
        Name
        unique_name
        name_class

Table2: Node
        tid
        rank
        path
        depth

Table3: Synonym
        node  (foreignkey to Node)
        name  (foreignkey to Name)
```

I want to extract tid and name based on a condition.

I know I can do this

```
names = Synonym.objects.filter(node__path__startswith=path, node__depth__gte=depth,
                                   name__name_class="ABC").order_by('node__path')

for n in names:
   print(n.node.tid, n.name.unique_name)
```

How can I make a query to extract tid and name in a single step avoiding the use of for loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`values(...)`**--(Django doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values)

```
result = Synonym.objects.filter(
    node__path__startswith=path,
    node__depth__gte=depth,
    name__name_class="ABC"
).order_by('node__path').values('node__tid', 'name__unique_name')

print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you @Arakkal Abu